# why load,render method is call when download png in highcharts

Tags: javascript, html, angular, highcharts, angular-highcharts

when I export the PNG from Highcharts it call load and render function that means it reloads the chart.

can we restrict calls to load and render events of highcharts when we export the png?

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and improve your question by providing among other a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: When the chart is exporting the load and render events fire because a new chart is created which has the same config - not mean that the current chart reloads.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel so can I restrict this events by any property?

Comment: @jayantikhutwad take a look at this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fhsL20ug/

Answer (score -1):

Thanks @SebastianWędzel for your help I will try you solution as well.
but this Solved my problem exporting: { chartOptions: { chart: { event:null }, }

Comment: It should be a comment instead of an answer.